# I have an original iPhone. How do I get it to work? 

Tags: iphone

I have an original iPhone and an iPhone 4.

Both phones are mine that I have owned since their respective launch days. That said I have not used my iPhone since I switched to the 4 and after I did that switch I forgot my passcode to unlock the screen. Since I couldn't get into it and I wanted to get my iPhone ready to just be a wifi remote around my apartment I went to iTunes and reset it back to factory defaults.

Now it just shows that 'connect to iTunes' screen and nothing else. Is there anyway to use it?  Or is my old iPhone bricked?

Comment: What happens when you connect it to iTunes?

Answer (score 4):

Put a valid AT&T sim (or the SIM from when you last activated this phone) in the slot.
Charge it for at least 15 minutes.
Restore again and post the specific error message from iTunes logs you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever jailbroken or unlocked your iPhone?

If not, you can try to put it in DFU (Device Firmware Update) mode and [download](http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/) and install an other copy of the iOS on your iPhone.

1. Download the new .ipsw file from the site mentioned above
2. Put your iPhone in [DFU Mode](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=1034)
3. Open iTunes and go to your iPhone tab (on the left side)
4. (If working with a Mac) `alt` + click and select the .ipsw file you just downloaded.
5. (If working with a Windows) `Ctrl` + click and select the .ipsw file you just downloaded.
6. iPhone should start recovering

If you have ever unlocked or jailbroken your iPhone, I think you should try to downgrade your baseband (Which I will explane when you confirm you did jailbrake/unlock your iPhone)

Comment: Instructions/references on what DFU mode is and how to access it are generally helpful to include in an answer such as this.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. I'll edit the question

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong but even a jailbreak won't bypass the iTunes activation screen.